# How to make phone call in iOS 10 using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10, phone-call

I want my app to be able to call a certain number when a button is clicked. I've tried to google it but there doesn't seem to have one for iOS 10 so far (where openURL is gone). Can someone put an example for me on how to do so? For instance like:

```
@IBAction func callPoliceButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Call the local Police department
}
```

Comment: Thank! I tried the same exact code however, when I change the google.com to "tel://120390129391824812988238197", nothing happened when I clicked on the button. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I was expecting it to have some pop-up and say "call 120390129391824812988238197 ?"

Answer (score 184):

You can call like this:

```
 if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(number)") {
     UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
 }
```

For **Swift 3+**, you can use like

```
guard let number = URL(string: "tel://" + number) else { return }
UIApplication.shared.open(number)
```

OR

```
UIApplication.shared.open(number, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Make sure you've scrubbed your phone number string to remove any instances of `(`, `)`, `-`, or `space`.

Comment: The `openURL` method is deprecated in iOS 10. The OP is asking what the replacement is.

Comment: `options` and `completionHandler` have default values so you can actually just do `UIApplication.shared.open(number)`

Comment: @Paolo Yes that's true.

Comment: what be the number in above @ParthAdroja

Comment: @DilipTiwari Number will be String.

Comment: Will it be empty right @ParthAdroja

Comment: @DilipTiwari No it wouldn't be empty. It will be like "tel://+911111111"

Comment: ok i got it @ParthAdroja

Comment: i can also pass string from json to this telephone string @ParthAdroja

Comment: @DilipTiwari Yes

Comment: Is there a way to get notified when the call has ended?

Answer (score 89):

### Task

Make a call with phone number validation

### Details

Tested on:

- Swift 5.2, Xcode 11.4 (11E146)

### Solution

```
// MARK: DataDetector

class DataDetector {

    private class func _find(all type: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType,
                             in string: String, iterationClosure: (String) -> Bool) {
        guard let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: type.rawValue) else { return }
        let range = NSRange(string.startIndex ..< string.endIndex, in: string)
        let matches = detector.matches(in: string, options: [], range: range)
        loop: for match in matches {
            for i in 0 ..< match.numberOfRanges {
                let nsrange = match.range(at: i)
                let startIndex = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: nsrange.lowerBound)
                let endIndex = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: nsrange.upperBound)
                let range = startIndex..<endIndex
                guard iterationClosure(String(string[range])) else { break loop }
            }
        }
    }

    class func find(all type: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType, in string: String) -> [String] {
        var results = [String]()
        _find(all: type, in: string) {
            results.append($0)
            return true
        }
        return results
    }

    class func first(type: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType, in string: String) -> String? {
        var result: String?
        _find(all: type, in: string) {
            result = $0
            return false
        }
        return result
    }
}

// MARK: PhoneNumber

struct PhoneNumber {
    private(set) var number: String
    init?(extractFrom string: String) {
        guard let phoneNumber = PhoneNumber.first(in: string) else { return nil }
        self = phoneNumber
    }

    private init (string: String) { self.number = string }

    func makeACall() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "tel://\(number.onlyDigits())"),
            UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) else { return }
        if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    }

    static func extractAll(from string: String) -> [PhoneNumber] {
        DataDetector.find(all: .phoneNumber, in: string)
            .compactMap {  PhoneNumber(string: $0) }
    }

    static func first(in string: String) -> PhoneNumber? {
        guard let phoneNumberString = DataDetector.first(type: .phoneNumber, in: string) else { return nil }
        return PhoneNumber(string: phoneNumberString)
    }
}

extension PhoneNumber: CustomStringConvertible { var description: String { number } }

// MARK: String extension

extension String {

    // MARK: Get remove all characters exept numbers

    func onlyDigits() -> String {
        let filtredUnicodeScalars = unicodeScalars.filter { CharacterSet.decimalDigits.contains($0) }
        return String(String.UnicodeScalarView(filtredUnicodeScalars))
    }

    var detectedPhoneNumbers: [PhoneNumber] { PhoneNumber.extractAll(from: self) }
    var detectedFirstPhoneNumber: PhoneNumber? { PhoneNumber.first(in: self) }
}
```

### Usage

```
PhoneNumber(extractFrom: "+1-(800)-123-4567")?.makeACall()

PhoneNumber.extractAll(from: "+1-(800)-123-4567 bla bla 1(617)111-22-33").last?.makeACall()

PhoneNumber.first(in: "+1-(800)-123-4567 bla bla 1(617)111-22-33")?.makeACall()

"+1-(800)-123-4567 bla bla 1(617)111-22-33".detectedPhoneNumbers[1].makeACall()
"+1-(800)-123-4567 bla bla 1(617)111-22-33".detectedFirstPhoneNumber?.makeACall()
```

### Full sample

> do not forget to **paste the solution code here**

```
func test() {
    isPhone("blabla")
    isPhone("+1(222)333-44-55")
    isPhone("+42 555.123.4567")
    isPhone("+1-(800)-123-4567")
    isPhone("+7 555 1234567")
    isPhone("+7(926)1234567")
    isPhone("(926) 1234567")
    isPhone("+79261234567")
    isPhone("926 1234567")
    isPhone("9261234567")
    isPhone("1234567")
    isPhone("123-4567")
    isPhone("123-89-01")
    isPhone("495 1234567")
    isPhone("469 123 45 67")
    isPhone("8 (926) 1234567")
    isPhone("89261234567")
    isPhone("926.123.4567")
    isPhone("415-555-1234")
    isPhone("650-555-2345")
    isPhone("(416)555-3456")
    isPhone("202 555 4567")
    isPhone("4035555678")
    isPhone(" 1 416 555 9292")
    isPhone("1(617)111-22-33!")
    isPhone("+44 1838 300284")
    isPhone("+44 1838 300284, 1 416 555 9292")
    isPhone("+44 1838 3d0384, 1 416 555 9292!")
}

private func isPhone(_ string: String) {
    let phoneNumbers = PhoneNumber.extractAll(from: string)
    let result = !phoneNumbers.isEmpty
    print("\(result ? "✅" : "❌") \(string) | detected phones: \(phoneNumbers)")
}
```

### Result

```
❌ blabla | detected phones: []
✅ +1(222)333-44-55 | detected phones: [+1(222)333-44-55]
✅ +42 555.123.4567 | detected phones: [555.123.4567]
✅ +1-(800)-123-4567 | detected phones: [+1-(800)-123-4567]
✅ +7 555 1234567 | detected phones: [+7 555 1234567]
✅ +7(926)1234567 | detected phones: [+7(926)1234567]
✅ (926) 1234567 | detected phones: [(926) 1234567]
✅ +79261234567 | detected phones: [+79261234567]
✅ 926 1234567 | detected phones: [926 1234567]
✅ 9261234567 | detected phones: [9261234567]
✅ 1234567 | detected phones: [1234567]
✅ 123-4567 | detected phones: [123-4567]
✅ 123-89-01 | detected phones: [123-89-01]
✅ 495 1234567 | detected phones: [495 1234567]
✅ 469 123 45 67 | detected phones: [469 123 45 67]
✅ 8 (926) 1234567 | detected phones: [8 (926) 1234567]
✅ 89261234567 | detected phones: [89261234567]
✅ 926.123.4567 | detected phones: [926.123.4567]
✅ 415-555-1234 | detected phones: [415-555-1234]
✅ 650-555-2345 | detected phones: [650-555-2345]
✅ (416)555-3456 | detected phones: [(416)555-3456]
✅ 202 555 4567 | detected phones: [202 555 4567]
✅ 4035555678 | detected phones: [4035555678]
✅  1 416 555 9292 | detected phones: [1 416 555 9292]
✅ 1(617)111-22-33! | detected phones: [1(617)111-22-33]
✅ +44 1838 300284 | detected phones: [+44 1838 300284]
✅ +44 1838 300284, 1 416 555 9292 | detected phones: [+44 1838 300284, 1 416 555 9292]
✅ +44 1838 3d0384, 1 416 555 9292! | detected phones: [1 416 555 9292]
```

Comment: I walked straight into upvoting with the fancy answer and bright colours/emojis... and then... ❌ +44 1838 300284 | 441838300284 | [not a phone number]. This is not working for me and returns false for everything

Comment: @paul_f did you tried to run the code on sample? Is is not working too?

Comment: Test works fine, whatever it is about my test case it does not work at all: "+44 1838 300284" for example. I think the spacing of the numbers is the issue. It's a common spacing here.

Comment: @paul_f check the answer. I updated the code

Comment: @VasilyBodnarchuk I actually wanted to upvote the answer but accidentally hit on the downvote button. 

Comment: @Jabbar thank you for the comment) because downvote for me means that something wrong with my code and I have to check it again. Glad to help!

Comment: @VasilyBodnarchuk No, there is nothing wrong with the code. It works perfectly. I just accidentally hit the downvote button.

Comment: @VasilyBodnarchuk, "phone:+1(617)111-22-33!".makeACall() is not working for me in Xcode 11.4, Can you help me out.

Comment: @SivabalaaJothibose Hello there! Did you tried to simulate the code on a real device?

Comment: @VasilyBodnarchuk Hi, In Real device. `guard isValid(regex: .phone)` is giving `false`.

Comment: @SivabalaaJothibose try again. I updated the code

Answer (score 23):

In Swift 4.2

```
func dialNumber(number : String) {

 if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(number)"),
   UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
      if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler:nil)
       } else {
           UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
       }
   } else {
            // add error message here 
   }
}
```

Call this like below

```
dialNumber(number: "+921111111222")
```

Hope this help.

Comment: This has already been posted many times...

Answer (score 18):

> Updated for Swift 3:

used below simple lines of code, if you want to make a phone call:

// function defination:

```
func makeAPhoneCall()  {
    let url: NSURL = URL(string: "TEL://1234567890")! as NSURL
    UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

// function call:  [Used anywhere in your code]

```
self.makeAPhoneCall()
```

**Note: Please run the app on a real device because it won't work on the simulator.**



Comment: it's does not consider the 0 in first position

Answer (score 7):

By mistake my answer was misplaced, please checkout this one:
You can use this:

```
guard let url = URL(string: "tel://\(yourNumber)") else {
return //be safe
}

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
UIApplication.shared.open(url)
} else {
UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```

> We need to check whether we're on iOS 10 or later As **'openURL' was deprecated in iOS 10.0**

Answer (score 6):

```
if let phoneCallURL:URL = URL(string: "tel:\(strPhoneNumber)") {
        let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
        if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "MyApp", message: "Are you sure you want to call \n\(self.strPhoneNumber)?", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let yesPressed = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                application.openURL(phoneCallURL)
            })
            let noPressed = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .default, handler: { (action) in

            })
            alertController.addAction(yesPressed)
            alertController.addAction(noPressed)
            present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: A better implementation.