# How do you validate an Australian phone number in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, regex, phone-number

I have implemented this nice solution provided by @Vasily-Bodnarchuk  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48870081/4200716)

I'd like to amend this so I can validate Australian numbers. The problem is that the RegEx validation in the code below appears to only validate US numbers. I have tried a few different values but none seem to work.

Any ideas?

```
extension String {

    enum RegularExpressions: String {
        case phone = "^\\s*(?:\\+?(\\d{1,3}))?([-. (]*(\\d{3})[-. )]*)?((\\d{3})[-. ]*(\\d{2,4})(?:[-.x ]*(\\d+))?)\\s*$"
    }

    func isValid(regex: RegularExpressions) -> Bool {
        return isValid(regex: regex.rawValue)
    }

    func isValid(regex: String) -> Bool {
        let matches = range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression)
        return matches != nil
    }

    func onlyDigits() -> String {
        let filtredUnicodeScalars = unicodeScalars.filter{CharacterSet.decimalDigits.contains($0)}
        return String(String.UnicodeScalarView(filtredUnicodeScalars))
    }

    func makeAColl() {
        if isValid(regex: .phone) {
            if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(self.onlyDigits())"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                if #available(iOS 10, *) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                } else {
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a few 3rd party libraries that validate and format phone numbers of any country. Try searching for one of those.

Comment: Please look at this too, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066329/regex-for-valid-international-mobile-phone-number

Answer (score 0):

To validate an Australian phone use this:

```
var phoneExpression = "/^\({0,1}((0|\+61)(2|4|3|7|8)){0,1}\){0,1}(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{2}(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{2}(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{1}(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{3}$/"

// Valid
var phoneNumber1 = "0411 234 567"
var phoneNumber2 = "(02) 3892 1111"
var phoneNumber3 = "38921111"
var phoneNumber4 = "0411234567"

// Invalid
var phoneNumber5 = "3892 11"
var phoneNumber6 = "diane 0411 234 567"
var phoneNumber7 = "bob"
```

[check more details](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2014/08/regular-expression-for-validating-australian-phone-numbers-including-landline-and-mobile/)

Comment: thanks, but I am getting a 'Invalid escape sequence in literal' error at every '\'

Comment: replace each \ with \\

Comment: ok that got rid of the errors, but the 'isValid(regex: .phone)' is returning false. So the regex expression is not working.

Comment: the regex worked without the first and last '/' forward slash. thanks for your help.

Comment: good @Roggie you are welcome