# How to make phone call with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swiftui

How to make a Phone Call in SwiftUI. Here is the sample code with Swift and UIKit:

```
guard let number = URL(string: "tel://" + "+1(222)333-44-55") else { return }
UIApplication.shared.open(number)
```

Here is the thread for Swift and the UIKit Version:

[How to make phone call in iOS 10 using Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40078370/how-to-make-phone-call-in-ios-10-using-swift?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create tappable url/phone number in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57582653/how-to-create-tappable-url-phone-number-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
let numberString = "111-222-3334"

Button(action: {
    let telephone = "tel://"
    let formattedString = telephone + numberString
    guard let url = URL(string: formattedString) else { return }
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
   }) {
   Text(numberString)
}
```

Comment: I wonder how this compares to using `URLComponents`, and setting the scheme to `"tel"`. It abstracts away the `://` so it feels more "proper", but I'm not sure if it's preferable